# Interferene of Gaussian beams with different waists

Tags: optics, interference

We want to calculate the interference pattern of two Gaussian beams with different focal points. We use the basic formula for a Gaussian beam

$$ \vec{E}(x, y, z) = E_0 \vec{x}\frac{\omega_0}{\omega_z}\exp{\left(\frac{-r^2}{\omega(z)^2}\right) \exp{(-i\left(kz + k\frac{r^2}{2 R(z)} - \psi(z)\right)}} $$

We note that the curvature $R$ and the waist $\omega(z)$ are symmetric around zero, whereas the Guoy phase $\psi(z)$ is anti-symmetric around zero. The above beam has its focal plane at $z=0$. We want two beams with focal planes $\Delta z$ apart, i.e. with focus at $z_{\pm} = \frac{\pm \Delta z}{2}$. To achieve this (approximation), we can translate a beam profile along the $z$ axis, i.e.
\begin{equation}
    \vec{E}_1(x, y, z) = \vec{E}(x, y, z + \frac{\Delta z}{2})
\end{equation}
This beam has its focal point at $z = -\frac{\Delta z}{2}$. Similarly,
\begin{equation}
    \vec{E}_2(x, y, z) = \vec{E}(x, y, z - \frac{\Delta z}{2})
\end{equation}
We want to evaluate
\begin{equation}
    Int_T = |\vec{E}_1 + \vec{E}_2|^2
\end{equation}
This is difficult for general $z$.
For $z = 0$, we can do some simplifications, because as mentioned above the waist is symmetric and the radius of curvature and Guoy phase are anti-symmetric.
We want to choose a certain phase offset $\Delta \phi$ for the second beam such that at $(x, y, z = 0, 0, 0)$ the beams destructively interfere. We apply this offset to the second beam.

Denoting the beam amplitude by $C(z)$, we get
\begin{multline}
    I(x, y, z=0) = |\vec{E}_1 + \vec{E}_2 e^{i\Delta \phi}|^2 = \\ 
    2C(z=0)^2 \times \left[1 + \cos{\left(k\Delta z + \frac{k r^2}{R(\Delta z / 2)} -  2\psi(\frac{\Delta z}{2}) + \Delta \phi \right)}\right]
\end{multline}
This gives a destructive interference condition for $z = 0$:

\begin{equation}
    \Delta \phi =  \pi - k \Delta z + 2 \psi(\frac{\Delta z}{2})
\end{equation}

This doesn't match with what I observe in an experiment for e.g. $\Delta z = 100 \mu m$. Where is the mistake in this formula?

Comment: Interference measurements are highly sensitive - submicron oscillations can ruin the experiment entirely. How are you measuring interference at a point between the focus of two beams? What kind of sensor do you have at that location? It’s much more likely you have an experiment issue than an algebra issue.

Comment: We have a camera at the location of interest (which records intensity). But that misses the point, I am questioning if the assumptions above (to write the Gaussian beams this way) or correct at all.

Comment: The question here is really about the ASSUMPTION and not about the calculation.

Comment: If you expect your experiment to show destructive interference as described by the formula, you are making more than one assumption. For example, the lasers operate entirely in the TEM$_{00}$ mode. The lasers are stable. The alignment is better than a wavelength of light. The sensor is only picking up light from the very small region where the destructive interference occurs. As @Jagerber48 said, look for experimental problems. But the assumption that a Gaussian beam has that form should be good.

Comment: The two beams have to be derived from the same laser, and even then the coherence length of the laser has to be long enough to maintain coherence between the two beams. The coherence length of many lasers is on the order < 1mm. (Need one laser unless the lasers are phase locked, which is a non-trivial effort.). Recommend you describe the experimental setup more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field for a Gaussian beam propagating in the $\hat{z}$ direction, polarized in the $\hat{x}$ direction, focused at position $z_0$ with waist size $w_0$, is given by
$$
\vec{E}(x, y, z) = \hat{x} E_0  \frac{w_0}{w(z-z_0)} \exp\left(\frac{-r^2}{w(z-z_0)^2}\right)\exp\left(-i\left(k(z-z_0) + k \frac{r^2}{2R(z-z_0)} - \psi(z-z_0)\right)\right)
$$
We'll consider the field on axis at $x=y=0$ so that $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = 0$.
We get

$$
\vec{E}(0, 0, z) = \hat{x} E_0 \frac{w_0}{w(z-z_0)} \exp\left(-i\left(k(z-z_0) - \psi(z-z_0)\right)\right)
$$

The OP wants to consider the interference at $z=0$ of two beams propagating along $\hat{z}$, polarized along $\hat{x}$ with waist size $w_0$ for both but focused at $\pm z_0$ respectively. I assume the amplitudes of the two beams are equal but that the phases may not be. We calculate this by

$$
\vec{E}_{tot}(0, 0, 0) = \hat{x} |E_0| \exp(i\phi_1) \frac{w_0}{w(-z_0)} \exp\left(-i\left(-kz_0 - \psi(-z_0)\right)\right) + \hat{x}|E_0| \exp(i\phi_2) \frac{w_0}{w(z_0)} \exp\left(-i\left(kz_0 - \psi(z_0)\right)\right)
$$

The OP correctly points out that $w(z)$ is symmetric and $\psi(z)$ is anti-symmetric so we get

\begin{align}
\vec{E}_{tot}(0, 0, 0) =& \hat{x}|E_0| \frac{w_0}{w(z_0)} \left(\exp(i\phi_1) \exp\left(ikz_0 -\psi(z_0) \right) + \exp(i\phi_2)\exp\left(-ikz_0 + \psi(z_0)\right)\right)\\
=& \hat{x}|E_0| \frac{w_0}{w(z_0)}\left(\exp(i(kz_0 - \psi(z_0) + \phi_1) + \exp(i(-kz_0 + \psi(z_0) + \phi_2)\right)
\end{align}

The expression in brackets is of the form $e^{i(A+B)} + e^{i(-A + C)}$. If we want destructive interference we need

\begin{align}
e^{i(A+B)} + e^{i(-A+C)} =& 0\\
e^{i(A+B)} = -e^{i(-A+C)} = e^{i(-A+C + \pi)}
\end{align}
which means

$$
A+B = -A+C+\pi + 2\pi n
$$
where $n$ is an integer so that
\begin{align}
C-B =& 2A - \pi - 2\pi n\\
\phi_2 - \phi_1 = \Delta \phi =& 2(kz_0 - \psi(z_0)) - \pi - 2\pi n\\
\Delta \phi = 2kz_0 - 2\psi(z_0) - \pi - 2\pi n&
\end{align}

The OP defines $\Delta z = 2z_0$ so that

$$
\Delta \phi = k\Delta z - 2\psi \left(\frac{\Delta z}{2}\right) - \pi - 2\pi n
$$

This agrees with the expression the OP gives module a minus sign, probably because of the opposite definition for $\Delta \phi$.